# How to use local value that is updated in for loop, smartpy tezos blockchain

Tags: blockchain, smartcontracts, tezos

I am studying smartpy on Tezos blockchain.
I am writing a smart contract and takeReward method.
But I am getting error when I compile this code from smartpy web IDE.

```
Error: Declaration Error
variable variable "x" escapes its scope. (inside_contract: true)
(__main__, line 72)
```

```
    @sp.entry_point
    def takeReward(self):
        raceId = self.data.raceId
        sp.verify(self.data.winner != 0)
        sp.verify(self.data.bets.contains(sp.sender))
        
        rewards = sp.mutez(0)
        records = self.data.bets[sp.sender]
        sp.for x in records:
            sp.if x.raceId == raceId:
                sp.if x.horseId == self.data.winner:
                    rewards += sp.split_tokens(x.amount, x.payout, 1)

        sp.if rewards > sp.mutez(0):
            sp.if sp.balance > rewards:
                sp.send(sp.sender, rewards)
```